# Snakemake doesn't recognize wildcard

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake

I try to run snakemake but I have this error message:

> Missing input files for rule mapping_SE:
>   Trimming/hira_2..trim.fastq

As you can see, the problem is that Snakemake expect two dots after the name of the sample, here "hira_2"

Actually, the file in the folder have this name :
hira_2.trim.fastq

I have define this rule within my snakefile :

```
rule mapping_SE:        
    input:
        r = 'Trimming/{sample}.trim.fastq'
```

Normally, the wildcards for 'sample'. should be "hira_1", "hira_2", etc

So I don't understand why Snakemake add another dot after the name of the sample ..

Comment: Quite clearly the value of `sample` contains a trailing dot. The `r = ` looks fishy but maybe I am just displaying my ignorance of Snakemake here.

Comment: You'll have to follow the stack of rules being used. What is the output of rule mapping_SE? Is there a dot missing (hence the added dot to {sample}? Otherwise it is one of the upstream rules. Try to make a minimal (working) example where this happens and share it, we unfortunately can't do more with the example's current state.

Comment: We will have to see more of your snakemake code to help you solve this. You can also try running snakemake with --debug-dag and see if that helps you track down the problem.